# Icons not loading for visualboyadvance-m in kubuntu

Tags: kde, icons, themes, gtk

Trying to run visualboyadvance-m on kubuntu (KDE) which starts however all the icons for the settings do not show, all the letters just show as squares, when running it from the terminal I get the following errors:

```
Gtk-Message: 16:56:04.990: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 16:56:04.991: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.098: Error loading theme icon 'view-fullscreen' for stock: Icon 'view-fullscreen' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.180: Error loading theme icon 'document-print' for stock: Icon 'document-print' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.183: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Icon 'document-save' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.279: Error loading theme icon 'document-open' for stock: Icon 'document-open' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.280: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Icon 'document-save' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.281: Error loading theme icon 'list-add' for stock: Icon 'list-add' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.281: Error loading theme icon 'list-remove' for stock: Icon 'list-remove' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.281: Error loading theme icon 'edit-clear' for stock: 
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.282: Error loading theme icon 'edit-select-all' for stock: Icon 'edit-select-all' not present in theme breeze
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 16:56:05.410: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
(visualboyadvance-m:4359): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:56:05.874: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Icon 'document-save' not present in theme breeze
** (visualboyadvance-m:4359): WARNING **: 16:56:30.912: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
```

As far as I can tell this is an issue with the kde theme breeze not having icons for this application. I have tried changing theme, but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm not sure about the solution to this, whether "stock icons" can be added to the theme or if there is a more versatile theme that may have the icons that I need. I am a beginner in this so forgive me if I have missed something glaringly obvious.